# Regular expressions in Java, can't search all HTML

Tags: java, regex

I'm working with Java regular expressions on Android platform.

I'm trying to search [this](http://krakow.dlastudenta.pl/teatr/repertuar_teatrow/teatry.html) HTML for defined a regular expression.

Here's my code:

```
    public void mainaaForWWW(String websiteSource){

    try {
        websiteSource = readDataFromWWW(websiteSource);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<String> cinemaArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern sample = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"theatre\">");
    Matcher secuence = sample.matcher(websiteSource);
    try {
        while (secuence.find()) {
            cinemaArray.add(secuence.group());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    titleTableForWWW = new String[cinemaArray.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < titleTableForWWW.length; i++)
        titleTableForWWW[i] = cinemaArray.get(i);
}
```

The problem is quite strange, because when I debug the code, `String websiteSource` is okay (all HTML files are completely loaded), but there's only 4 while loops. In the HTML document I found manually 11 matches. This regex is simplified only to find what's going on. Any ideas?

Ok, my bad. I found a solution:

So, here's my code responsible for writing `HTML` source code to `String`:

```
public String readDataFromWWW(String UrlAdress) throws IOException
    {

        String line = null;
        URL url = new URL(UrlAdress);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-2"));
        while (rd.readLine() != null) {
            line += rd.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println(line);

        return line;
```

I think that reading to string that way, may something messed up, so I replaced this method by this one:

```
public String readDataFromWWW(String UrlAdress) throws IOException
    {
        String wyraz = "";

         try {
                String webPage = UrlAdress;
                URL url = new URL(webPage);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-2");

                int numCharsRead;
                char[] charArray = new char[1024];
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                    sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
                }
                wyraz = sb.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return wyraz;
    }
```

And everything works FINE! Thanks a lot for clues and help. I think the problem was connected with newline durring writing `String`, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex? Not unless you want to [summon Cthulhu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1223693)!

Comment: To be literal, it's parsing the String object. I was verified the content of this String and it's ok.

Comment: @MariuszChw: There is nothing wrong with your regex, or the HTML file (I read the HTML file as UTF-8). Check whether the transfer terminate half way, or if there is something wrong with encoding.

Comment: Length of string compare to html is ok, so there's no problem with transfer. I'm tried ISO-8859-2 and UTF-8 coding, the result is these same: only 4 loops. I really have no idea what's wrong :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/870248

Comment: I'd try `Pattern sample = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("<div class=\"theatre\">"));` instead just to be safe.

Comment: I tried this, and nothing new in this riddle :)

Comment: Have you tried `System.out.println(websiteSource);` and checking whether something went wrong (and that you can see the 11 occurrences)?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I also use debugger for look inside of String value, and it's ok

Comment: I suggest to use http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net for parsing html

Comment: In case the links to the Cthulhu answer are not clear, DO NOT PARSE HTML WITH REGEX.  Your may get your code to work today, but it will be very brittle. Use a real HTML parser.

Comment: I fought the regex is simpliest way to get specified objects data from html. Ok, so I know now - it's bad practice to use regex with html. Any alternative ways?